# Loop R function agruments and agruments get value for user input or defult value from agruments name

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I had the follwoing function that will have some computations on one data frame, there will be many variables(much more than 3) used in the function, the variables will be updated by user input or set a defaul value.

```r
f <- function(data_in,
              var_v1 = NULL,
              var_v2 = NULL,
              var_v3 = NULL) {
  
  stopifnot(!missing(data_in), is.data.frame(data_in))

  args <- formals()
  for (i in seq_along(args)) {
    arg <- names(args)[[i]]
    if (stringr::str_starts(arg, "var")) {
      # get(arg,envir = as.environment(data_in))
      if (TRUE) { # if the var_v have user input then use the user input
        assign(arg, rlang::as_name(get(arg)), envir = environment())
      } else {
        # if NULL use the second part of aguments, e.g. var_v1 -> var_v1 = "v1"
        assign(arg, stringr::str_replace(arg, "var_", "."), envir = environment())
      }
    }
  }

  # just for example, can be other complex computation based on these columns
  data_in %>% dplyr::mutate(
    x1 = .data[[var_v1]],
    x2 = .data[[var_v2]],
    x3 = .data[[var_v3]]
  )
}
```

If we can loop the args, then the parameter value of varaibles(prefix with `var_`) can be set by user when calling function, or default value based on the arguemnt names(e.g. the rgith part `v1`, seperated by `_`).

I test some method in the following code, but not found a right solution,

```r
  # get(arg,envir = as.environment(data_in))
      if (TRUE) { # if the var_v have user input then use the user input
```

or I will repeat the code for each var argruments.

```r
if (!is.null(var_v1)){
  var_v1 <- as.character(substitute(var_v1))
} else {
  var_v1 <- "v1"
}
```

## the test data

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~v1, ~v2, ~v3, ~v_x,
  "v1", "v2", "v3", "v_x"
)
```

## call by defult `f(df)`

### arguments value set to: `var_v1 = v1, var_v2 = v2, var_v3 = v3`

```r
# f(df)
df1 <- df[,c("v1","v2","v3")] 
names(df1) <- c("x1","x2","x3")
df1
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   x1    x2    x3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 v1    v2    v3
```

## call with user input `f(df, var_v1 = v_x)`

### arguments value set to: `var_v1 = v_x, var_v2 = v2, var_v3 = v3`

```r
# f(df, var_v1 = v_x)
df2 <- df[,c("v_x","v2","v3")]
names(df2) <- c("x1","x2","x3")
df2
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   x1    x2    x3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 v_x   v2    v3
```

Comment: If you set a default in the `function()` statement instead of `NULL1` then it will be used unless the user provides an alternative, e.g. `var_v1 = "v1"` will default to `v1` unless specified in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is to set defalt value to arguments from arguments name.

```r
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(data_in,
              var_v1 = NULL,
              var_v2  = NULL,
              var_v3  = NULL) {
  
  stopifnot(!missing(data_in), is.data.frame(data_in))
  
  args <- formals()
  for (i in seq_along(args)) {
    arg <- names(args)[[i]]
    if (stringr::str_starts(arg, "var")) {
      eval(parse(text = paste0(arg, " <- rlang::enquo(", arg, ")")))
      if (!rlang::quo_is_null(get(arg))) {
        assign(arg, rlang::as_name(get(arg)), envir = environment())
      } else {
        assign(arg, stringr::str_replace(arg, "var_", ""), envir = environment())
      }
    }
  }
  
  data_in %>% dplyr::mutate(
    x = .data[[var_v1]],
    x2 = .data[[var_v2]],
    x3 = .data[[var_v3]]
  )
}

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~v1, ~v2, ~v3, ~v_x,
  "v1", "v2", "v3", "v_x"
)

f(df)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 7
#>   v1    v2    v3    v_x   x     x2    x3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 v1    v2    v3    v_x   v1    v2    v3

f(df, var_v1=v_x)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 7
#>   v1    v2    v3    v_x   x     x2    x3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 v1    v2    v3    v_x   v_x   v2    v3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>